# How to undo/revert git clone --mirror command?

Tags: git

I want to revert/undo the following command:

`git clone --mirror <mygitrepository>`

I was testing something and it didn't work as expected so I now want to do undo this command. I can see that extra files and folders have been pulled down into my local directory which I don't want.

I haven't committed anything, I've just run the above command.

How do I undo this?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out it doesn't matter. I could in theory just clone from the repository again and delete the existing directory on my local.